# Transaction mq +hibernate +oracle

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, ibm-mq, xa

we are developing an application with following characteristics:
standalone java application
Hibernate 4
WebSphere MQ v6.2
Oracle 11gR2

Interaction with MQ - only native mq api. 
We need to synchronize transactions between Websphere MQ and Oracle.
Do we really need XA? Somebody give an example?

Comment: What means synchronize? or do you want to make changes to oracle and mq series as part of the same transaction?

Comment: Yes, in same transaction.

Comment: i'm find solution http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=54489&sid=2af9c9d81ea54b31738209c36375f2eb. But it a half. Can i set datasource to entitymanagerfactory programmatically or in pesistence.xml?